# The requested component ("varchar") is not found

Tags: magento2

When I am trying to export customer csv file then following error is show:

> The requested component ("varchar") is not found. Before using, you
>   must add the implementation.

Comment: are you using any third-party module?

Comment: @MohitRane, No I am not using any third-party module for customer

Comment: which Magento version are you using?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.4